# textarea with rows 4 but trimmed after submit to get the value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a `<textarea>` with rows set to 4 in HTML. After form submission, I found that the text written within the `<textarea>` got trimmed to remaining first 4 rows. What I really want is limit what textbox to exactly 4 rows, so user will only type 4 rows. Worried they will hack in and input more into the textbox.

For example, if I type the following inside the `<textarea>`:

> A (New line character)
>   B (New line character)
>   C (New line character)
>   D (New line character)
>   E

What is being stored is:

> A
>   B
>   C
>   D

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="descriptionTextarea" name="descriptionTextarea" rows="4"  required="true"  maxlength="450"></textarea>
```

And I find out here is the catch, the row limitation don't work on all browsers, in some browsers user can type in a lot of lines and really what's being stored is just the first few rows (which is what the limit is).

Any Idea?!

Comment: I still can't understand what you're after. Do you want to limit the output to 4 rows (or lines, to be precise) or not? Either way, setting "rows" attribute to 4 is not going to help you in any way: it only limits the visible size of the textarea, but not what user actually enters there.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov Sorry let me edit the question

Comment: Which browser doesn't return what you expect? It would be nice if you provide all of the information you have.

Comment: @AzizSaleh Firefox and Chrome

Comment: You must not rely on HTML or JavaScript when you try to limit user's input. Both can be modified or disabled very easily on the client's end. You have to take care of it in your backend PHP script, which actually stores the data. It would be nice to see it (or some of it) here too, by the way.

Comment: i would drop the textarea and use 4 text inputs myself.

Comment: There must be something modifying the textarea. Works fine for me @ http://main.xfiddle.com/code_69982289.php

Comment: @Dagon that's defeating the purpose of having a textarea

Comment: @AzizSaleh Could it be the browser?

Comment: If I get it right, you have misunderstood the `row` property functionality of the `textarea`. as @SergeyVidusov mentioned It does **NOT** mean the limitation of what the users can type. it only limits the visible rows of text shown in browser and then if you have more than 4 rows, a scrollbar will appear. for limiting the inputted text to only 4 rows, on client-side you have to use some `js functions or plugins`  but you **HAVE** to handle it on the server-side aswell...

Comment: because the textarea is the wrong form input to use

Comment: @EhsanT Could you provide some sample code in both client and server side handling?

Comment: Just count no. of "enter " in the submitted string.

Comment: @KNVB would this always works?

Comment: @RyanFung "SO" is not a good place to ask for sample code. you have to do the coding and if you had problems with your code, then post your code and question about the problem here and then ask for help on it... I gave you the hint on what you should do on both client and server side. Please do some research on them and write some codes and if you had problems with them, please come back and we will be more than happy to help you on them...

Comment: @EhsanT Sorry got lazy here, I will come back with my code later on. Thanks